# How do I know if WINE is installed?

Tags: wine

The store says WINE is installed, but I don't see it in my apps, or an option to use WINE to open a .exe file.

Comment: You could simply type in `wine --version` in a terminal window.

Comment: @muru: I think the question is actually founded in the misunderstanding that WINE has a graphical user interface and/or creates an application starter for itself.

Comment: @DavidFoerster wine does usually add 2-3 launchers (one for uninstalling software, and a couple of others that I don't recall at the moment), and the Wine launcher should show up in the open with menu.

Comment: @muru: I think those only appear (in the per-user application launcher directory) once you create your first Wine prefix. The only Wine-related application launcher on my system that doesn't have `NoDisplay=true` (and I didn't touch those in `/usr/share/applications/`) is for Winetricks which is a separate package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find installed WINE and WINE-related packages with the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep -i wine
```

You can find its default prefix with its size by

```
ls -ld ~/.wine
du -sh ~/.wine/*
```

and other prefixes (usually created by `winetricks`) with

```
ls -ld ~/.local/share/wineprefixes/*
du -sh ~/.local/share/wineprefixes/*
```

Comment: I don't get why a grep on dpkg -l should be better than the builtin status function...

Answer (score 3):

To rightfully see if WINE is installed you should run:

```
which wine
```

The `which` command will either return an exit status of 0 if installed or a 1 if not installed...

To find the exit status of the command, simply run:

```
echo $?
```

It is a very simple yet important command to know about...

Comment: +1 because it's the fastest and easiest way to check. But it should be mentioned, that this does not really look if something is installed. `sudo touch /usr/bin/wine && chmod +x  /usr/bin/wine` would be enough to trick it.

Comment: @RoVo True, but I doubt that would be applying in this case... But thanks for mentioning that!

Comment: Actually, while the exit code is `0` if installed and `1` if not, what `which wine` will output is the path where wine is installed, typically  `/usr/bin/wine`

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you either included how to obtain the exit code or what is displayed when wine is installed.

Comment: +1. Added a use case for If condition ```#!/bin/bash
winetricksInstalled() {
    command=$(which winetricks)
    return $(echo $?)
}
if $(winetricksInstalled) ; then
    echo "installed"
else
    echo "Not installed"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-s` (status) switch of `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -s wine
```

Returns `0` if installed or `1` if the program is not installed.

---

Another way to see if a package is installed and which version (`Installed: [...]`). You also see which version would be installed (`Candidate: [...]`).

```
apt-cache policy <package name>
apt-cache policy wine
```

Advantage of `apt-cache`: You can use wildcards(`*`) if you don't know the exact package name.

Comment: Regarding `dpkg -s wine`: I'm not convinced that most users are even aware that they can obtain the exit code of a program with `echo $?` so the output of the command is likely more useful to most users than the exit code it returns.